# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> I need to prove that
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n k^p
>  = \frac{1}{p+1}
> $$

By Stulz lemma, $$\frac{(n+1)^{p}}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1}$$
and
$$\frac{(n+1)^{p}}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}\geq\frac{1}{\frac{p+1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\rightarrow  \frac{1}{1+p}$$

And know I'm stuck..

Comment: Can you explain the equality?  $$\frac{(n+1)^{p}}{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p}$$ How can $n$ go to infinity on the RHS but not on the LHS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^m}{n^{m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150391/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac-sum-k-1n-kmnm1)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\int_1^nx^p dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^p \leq \int_1^{n+1}x^p dx$$

Precalculus:

Use induction. For the upper bound assume that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p \leq \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

holds. Then show that $(n+1)^p + \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1} \leq \frac{(n+2)^{p+1}}{p+1}$ to conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^p \leq \frac{(n+2)^{p+1}}{p+1}$ and since it holds for $n=1$ it follows by induction that the inequality hold for all $n$. For the lower bound assume that

$$\frac{n^{p+1}-1}{p+1}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^p$$

holds. Then show that  $\frac{n^{p+1}-1}{p+1} + (n+1)^p\geq \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$ and conclude.

Comment: Pre calculus . I cant use integrals

Comment: @Eyalbason I see. Is induction fine? I added how one can do this inductively (though now seeing Jack's answer below I would instead go for this I were you).

Answer (score 5):

We have:
$$ k(k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k-p+1)=p!\binom{k}{p}\leq k^p \leq p!\binom{k+p}{p}=(k+p)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k+1). $$
Summing over $k$:
$$ p!\binom{n+1}{p+1}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p\leq p!\binom{n+p+1}{p+1} $$
hence:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p = \frac{1}{p+1}$$
follows by squeezing.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over n^{p + 1}}\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}k^{p}
    ={1 \over p + 1}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over n^{p + 1}}\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}k^{p}}
> =\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over n}\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}\pars{k \over n}^{p}
> =\int_{0}^{1}x^{p}\,\dd x
> =\left.{x^{p + 1} \over p + 1}\right\vert_{\, x\ =\ 0}^{\,x\ =\ 1}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over p + 1}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use the Faulhaber formula:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \dfrac1{p+1} \sum_{j=0}^p (-1)^j \dbinom{p+1}j B_j n^{p+1-j}$$
where $B_j$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I can't use both of the suggestions. I'm looking for something more elementry..